# Updating state based on multiple other state values using hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

### Asynchronous state updates and class components

We are warned in the React State and Lifecycle docs [that state updates may be asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous). And for that reason we should not rely on their values for calculating next state:

```js
// Wrong
this.setState({
  counter: this.state.counter + this.props.increment
})
```

Instead we should use the function update form of `setState` to ensure we have the correct previous values of state:

```js
// Correct
this.setState((state, props) => ({
  counter: state.counter + props.increment
}))
```

This example applies to class components where the entire state is available for reference in the function callback.

### Function components and useState

When defining function components we can have separate value for our state like so:

```js
function MyComponent() {
  const [a, setA] = useState(1)
  const [b, setB] = useState(2)
}
```

Presumably the same asychronous rules apply, which is why the `setA` function provided by the `useState` hook also accepts a function argument to update it, like so:

```js
function MyComponent() {
  const [a, setA] = useState(1)
  const [b, setB] = useState(2)
  const onClick = () => {
    setA(a => a + 1)
  }
  return <>
    <div>a: {a}</div>
    <div>b: {b}</div>
    <button onClick={onClick}>Update a</button>
  </>
}
```

### Updating state based on multiple other state values in function components

What happens when we want to update `a` based on the value of `b`? Based on the earlier problems with state updates being asychronous, we don't want to just reference `b` directly, but instead recieve its value using the function version of set state.

This can be achieve by putting all our state onto a single object like this:

```js
function MyComponent() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ a: 1, b: 2 })
  const onClick = () => {
    setState(state => ({ b: state.b, a: state.a + state.b }))
  }
  return <>
    <div>a: {state.a}</div>
    <div>b: {state.b}</div>
    <button onClick={onClick}>Update a based on b</button>
  </>
}
```

This makes sense to me.

My question is: is using a combined object as described above (or `useReducer`) the only appropriate and safe way to update a state value based on the value of multiple other pieces of state when using hooks?

Or is it ever appropriate to just reference the variable via closure like so (I don't this would be correct):

```js
function MyComponent() {
  const [a, setA] = useState(1)
  const [b, setB] = useState(2)
  const onClick = () => {
    setA(a => a + b)
  }
  return <>
    <div>a: {a}</div>
    <div>b: {b}</div>
    <button onClick={onClick}>Update a</button>
  </>
}
```

Or some other way?

---

Edit:

A bit more digging and I've come across this blog post by Dan Abramov [React UI as a Runtime - Batching](https://overreacted.io/react-as-a-ui-runtime/#batching). In it he recommends `useReducer` for complicated state update cases:

> When state logic gets more complex than a few setState calls, I recommend expressing it as a local state reducer with the `useReducer` Hook.

So perhaps combined state objects or `useReducer` is the way.

Answer (score 2):

That's where `React.useEffect` come into play:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [a, setA] = React.useState();
  const [b, setB] = React.useState();
  const [c, setC] = React.useState();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setA(5);
    setB(5);
  }, []);

  React.useEffect(() => setC(a + b), [a, b]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{c}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The first `React.useEffect` sets a and b when the component is being rendered.
The second  `React.useEffect` sets c according to a and b, and it'll be fired when one of the following dependencies (`a` or `b`) will be changed.

[See live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-heisenberg-mwiiz?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Interesting approach, I hadn't thought to use `useEffect` with a dependency array to trigger dependent state updates. That does seem to work when you're not setting some state that you're also referencing. But in the example I gave above where a = a + b I think this wouldn't work as it would infinitely recurse. Do you tend to handle dependent state updates like this in real code? Or use the dependent state on a shared object approach?